# TURN if the media-server has a public ip and is not behind NAT

Tags: webrtc, turn

For a WebRTC peer connection between a mobile client and a media server, would we need a TURN server if the media-server has a public IP and is not sitting behind a NAT?

Comment: No. If one peer has a public IP then TURN should not be required (there could be security/policy settings that mandate TURN for other reasons).

Comment: Thanks, This would be true even if the other peer is behind symmetric NAT?

Comment: Yep. A TURN server is really just a dumb media server which relays traffic from one socket to another. Hence if a TURN server can connect two peers so can a media server.